# Best way to round down in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form, when a user fills in the total number of bottles they have, it inserts into a database and then should sum up how many cases there are.

For example in wine - there are 12 bottle cases, if a user puts in 100 bottles, it should divide this by 12 and give the sum of 8.33333333.

```
$bottles = "100";
```

What is the best way to round this down to just the number 8 and then work out how many bottles are left that never made it into a full case?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Try googling `php round down`, literally the first result http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php.

Comment: `floor()` as well. Was any research done?

Comment: "best way to round down"? What are your functional and non-functional requirements with which you would reject non-best ways? I'm pretty sure most ways to round down would work equally well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `floor` to round down, and the modulo (`%`) operator to determine how many bottles are left.

```
$bottles = 100;
$bottles_per_case = 12;

print "There are " . floor($bottles / $bottles_per_case) . " cases...";
print "With " . ($bottles % $bottles_per_case) . " bottles left over";
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `floor`

```
$bottles = "100";
$case = floor( $bottles / 12 );

echo $case;
```

Will result to **8**

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

---

If you want to check the bottles left, you can use modulo

```
$bottles = "100";
$left = $bottles % 12;
```

Will result to **4**

Comment: the OP also asked `and then work out how many bottles are left that never made it into a full case`

Comment: @Sean, Updated.

Comment: Curious: Is there a reason that you gave `$bottles` a _string_ value of "100"?

Comment: @RToyo That is based on the question. The given is string 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bottles = "100";
$case = (int) $bottles / 12 ;
echo $case;
$left = $bottles % 12;
echo '<br>left: ' . $left;
```